# Overcome differences in node and browserify path resolving

Tags: node.js, browserify

I'm writing a module for a react app that needs to be included on both the backend and frontend.

At some point in my code, I'm requiring some svg file (for which I use a browserify module, but this has nothing to do with the question).

For example I have in my `./src/js/components/tools/svg.js` the following bit of code:

```
// ...
var BACKEND = /* code to detect if this is running on browser or on node */;

var svg;
if ( BACKEND ) {
  svg  = require("./../../../icon/" + this.props.icon + ".svg");
} else {
  svg  = require("./src/icon/" + this.props.icon + ".svg");
}
// ....
```

I use browserify's `require` option to require all the svg files at bundle-time:

```
browserify({
  paths: ['./src/icon'],
})
.transform(/* svg tansformer */)
.require(glob.sync("./src/icon/*.svg")) // <-- svg's get added here
.add("./src/main.js"); // main entry point
```

However this conflicts with how node resolves the filenames. It cannot find `./src/icon/` from `./src/js/components/tools/svg.js`.

This is why I have to guard the require with the `BACKEN` clause. This breaks my eyes though and I would like to just be able to write:

```
var svg = require('./src/icon/' + this.props.icon + '.svg');
```

I've tried two things so far:

#### fix node to find `./src/icon`

I can use `` export NODE_PATH=`cwd` `` to allow node to look for `src/icon` from `./`. This allows me to write:

```
var svg = require('src/icon/' + this.props.icon + '.svg');
```

in the backend. But, since browserify only accepts `paths` that start with `./` (thus, ignoring `src/icon`) this will not resolve on the frontend.

#### fix browserify to use `../../../icon/`

Haven't got this to work either because of the same reason: browserify only accepts paths that start with `./`.

Comment: IIRC, Browserify doesn't allow dynamically generated paths anyway.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't. That's why I need the `browserify.require` call. It forces browserify to include all the provided paths. These are then available in the browser. but this only works if the paths start with `./`....

Comment: Oh I see. Will have a play with this when I get time if no-one answers first.

Answer (score 1):

It's considered bad practice doing conditional requires when using Browserify because it can't evaluate the code at "compile time" and will always attempt to load all the files.

To load different files in the browser environment than on node is easy:
Add a `"browser"` field to your package.json that points to the browser main file. Use `"main"` for the node main file. Then just require the module.

You can do the same thing with sub folders within your project. Just add a package.json file with `"private": true` and both, the `main` and the `browser` properties and require the folder path.

Comment: I'm working on a browserified angular app that is doing some dynamic requires.  I understand your approach, but I'm curious why conditional requires are considered bad practice since JavaScript is a dynamic language after all.  Paraphrasing Crockford - compile errors aren't generally the ones I care much about.

Comment: I wouldn't generalize this statement. But dynamic requires are most probably not working properly with Browserify.

Comment: Yeah I think I actually stumbled upon that myself yesterday.  Took me quite a while to realize my require was not working because I was generating the require string in a lazily evaluated function.